# "Error 1962: No operating system found" while installing Ubuntu 12 on Lenovo ThinkCentre Edge 72 - i7 3770S

Tags: boot, system-installation, lenovo

I have tried for several days to install Ubuntu on my new computer which had Windows pre-installed. I have tried to install the 64-bit 12.10 and 12.04. I have also tried the 32-bit version of 12.04. After having installed the OS, the computer restarts, then displays:

```
Error 1962: No operating system found. Press any key to repeat boot sequence.
```

I have tried to follow the advice in different threads on the forum, but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have  found a workaround.

With Super Grub 2 Disk you can boot machine from CD.

1. Download from:
   http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/
   Select the (ISO) format.
2. Burn the ISO to CD using image burning software.
3. Power on the machine with the CD in the drive to boot.